# Sum document fields where the reference id is equal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have these documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c42bc26296623b0056515a"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565153")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565155")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 5,
    "goals_against" : 2,
    "goals_difference" : 3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 1,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 0,
    "points" : 3
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c42bc26296623b0056515b"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565154")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565155")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 2,
    "goals_against" : 5,
    "goals_difference" : -3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 0,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 1,
    "points" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c4eb5aaa5d6523c83f59c0"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565153")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565156")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 5,
    "goals_against" : 2,
    "goals_difference" : 3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 1,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 0,
    "points" : 3
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c4eb5aaa5d6523c83f59c1"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565154")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565156")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 2,
    "goals_against" : 5,
    "goals_difference" : -3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 0,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 1,
    "points" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c4eb99aa5d6523c83f59c4"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565153")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565157")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 5,
    "goals_against" : 2,
    "goals_difference" : 3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 1,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 0,
    "points" : 3
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c4eb99aa5d6523c83f59c5"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565154")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565157")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 2,
    "goals_against" : 5,
    "goals_difference" : -3,
    "matches_played" : 1,
    "won_matches" : 0,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 1,
    "points" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to get all the docs with the `goals_favor, goals_against, goals_difference, match_played, won_matches, tied_matches, lost_matches, and points` summed fields, where the reference IDs in the `team` field are the same, note that there are three documents with the following id in the team field `'60c42acf6296623b00565153'` and the remaining three with the id `'60c42acf6296623b00565154'`, so I would like a structure similar to the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c42bc26296623b0056515a"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565153")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565155")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 15,
    "goals_against" : 6,
    "goals_difference" : 9,
    "matches_played" : 3,
    "won_matches" : 3,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 0,
    "points" : 9
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c42bc26296623b0056515b"),
    "team" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42acf6296623b00565154")
    ],
    "matchday" : [ 
        ObjectId("60c42b386296623b00565155")
    ],
    "goals_favor" : 6,
    "goals_against" : 15,
    "goals_difference" : -9,
    "matches_played" : 3,
    "won_matches" : 0,
    "tied_matches" : 0,
    "lost_matches" : 3,
    "points" : 0
}
```

I have tried this but cannot follow:

```
const ids = ['60c42acf6296623b00565153', '60c42acf6296623b00565154']

TeamsDetails.aggregate([
                        { $match: { "team": { $in: ids } } },
                        { $group: { _id: "$_id", total: { $sum: "$points" } } },
                    ]).exec((error, find) => {
                        //Do something
                    })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and group by `team`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // match stage
  {
    $unwind: "$team"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$team",
      "points": {
        "$sum": "$points"
      },
      goals_favor: {
        $sum: "$goals_favor"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q_oOqu-KejS)**